# Classic ASP SQL Server Database Connection

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am aiming to create a very basic web based DBMS for Microsoft SQL Server. However, in order to connect to a SQL Server database you seem to require a ODBC connection on the server. Is there any possible way to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't stated which version of SQLServer but you can use OLEDB connection in ASP.

```
<%

Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = Northwind; User Id = sa; Password="

If conn.errors.count = 0 Then   
   Response.Write "Connected OK"
End If

%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer we are using 2005 / 2008. 

So this connection method means an ODBC connection does not need to be created on the server?

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Comment: Yes it should be fine.  This site also a good source of information http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-my-connection-string-look-like.html 

And this one is always good when you just can't remember the connection string you need.  www.connectionstrings.com

Hope this helps

Barry